# Create a VIEW spanning an unknown number of databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, multiple-tables

- I have a "master" database that contains a table with ServerName and
  DatabaseName columns.
- Each row represents a "child" database which might be on the same or
  different server.
- There will always be at least 1 row but there can theoretically be an
  unlimited number of rows.
- In each "child" database there is TableA with ColumnA.

How do I create a view or function (perhaps returns xml) in the master that will union all ColumnA values across all databases?

Something like this:

```
USE Master;
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
AS
    SELECT ColumnA FROM Server1.database1.dbo.TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ColumnA FROM Server1.database2.dbo.TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ColumnA FROM Server2.database1.dbo.TableA;
GO
```

but obviously we are reading the servername and database name out of the master table.

Comment: don't see any other way other than using a cursor and loop thorough and get the unioned columned data.

Comment: But even then wouldn't it be dynamic like ..+ ServerValue + '].[' + DbValue + '].dbo.TableA.ColumnA - would it need an exec for every row, and exec wouldnt work in a function. Tricky

Comment: not an answer but something to think about. given that you store all your "child" connection strings in a database table in the "master" database I hope you have tight security around your "master" database or one table gets exploited and every database is exploited.

Answer (score 3):

If you are maintaining a master list, then this list needs to be updated.  This gives you an opportunity to add/modify a trigger or stored procedure that does the update.

In other words, you want a trigger on the master table that will reconstruct the view.  Something like this:

```
create trigger dbo.trigger_mastertable_change on dbo.atable
for insert, update, delete
as begin
    declare @sql = nvarchar(max);

    select @sql = stuff((select 'union all ' +
                         replace(replace('select columnA from <server>.<database>.dbo.Table1',
                                         '<database>', quotename(t.databasename),
                                        ), '<server>', quotename(t.servername)
                                )
                          from dbo.atable
                          for xml path ('')
                        ), 1, 10, '');

    select @sql = 'alter view myview as ' + @sql;
    exec sp_executesql @sql;
end;
```

Dynamic SQL in triggers is generally not recommended, because of the locking issue.  If you have stored procedure(s) for changing the table, then it is better to put the logic there.

Comment: It would be more secure to use `QUOTENAME` function to quote server and database names: `REPLACE(REPLACE('SELECT columnA FROM <server>.<database>dbo.Table1', '<database>', QUOTENAME(t.databasename)), '<server>', QUOTENAME(t.severname))`

Comment: @DmitrySavchenko . . . That is a very good point.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Technically they are right. Circumventing the SQL restrictions are not something I would recommend. CLR methods provide one other optional path in addition to the above.

However, if you did feel the desperate desire to "break the rules", I don't recommend this as best practise, but you could give thought to master.dbo.xp_cmdshell and use a script to force a rebuild of a view etc. That script would indeed allow for EXEC and dynamic.

Disclaimer: Not a recommendation :)

(Just to prove there are always ways)

Comment: I am of course assuming this isn't some manual workaround for a partitioned database. Look up Partitioning.